# docker COPY not working when deploying with docker-machine

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm using docker-compose, with one image built with a dockerfile, the others are standard images. The image controlled by the dockerfile ('website') has 
COPY . /gp_flask 
(the directory is created earlier). 
It works fine when

```
docker-compose up --build
```

happens on my Ubuntu machine. It copies a directory structure.

However, when I use an EC2 docker-machine, there is no content in the directory (in docker)
I added

```
RUN ls -la  /gp_flask
```

immediately after the COPY, and it shows all the content correctly.
The only commands which follow are `EXPOSE` ports and `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]`

COPY commands to copy config files for supervisord and nginx do work fine.

yet after the build process is finished, one of the other containers fails as it can't find something in /gp_flask, and sure enough if I
docker-compose exec website /bin/bash 
the directory /gp_flask 
is now empty.

This only happens when I am running in a docker-machine environment. docker-compose on my local machine works fine.

Also, if I use docker-machine and start two shells with `eval "$(docker-machine env gpflask)"` and then in one I do:

```
 docker build -t gp_flask .
```

and in the other:

```
docker exec -it mad_fermat /bin/bash
```

then I can see that COPY worked (on the EC2 docker engine instance).

So this means that something about docker-compose is different on the remote docker engine.  The success of the `RUN ls` after the `COPY` seems to indicate that the copy is working but a later image in the build process removes it,although there are basically no following commands.

```
FROM python:3.5
MAINTAINER Tim Richardson <tim@growthpath.com.au>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -qq -y vim --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -qq -y nginx --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -qq -y supervisor --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -qq -y python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools --no-insta
ll-recommends
# RUN apt-get install -qq -y openssh-server --no-install-recommends
#RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY requirements requirements
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

ENV INSTALL_PATH /gp_flask
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY . /gp_flask
RUN ls -la  /gp_flask

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
#note that if you change the name of the app, you have to change the command lin
e to gunicorn
#gunicorn is started in supervisord setup
#CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8001 --access-logfile - "dear_flask.app:create_app()"

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

and here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.5'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass devpassword
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      /usr/bin/supervisord
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/gp_flask'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '5000:5000'
      - '5001:5001'

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery worker -l debug -A dear_flask.dear.tasks
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/gp_flask'

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
```

and here is supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
loglevel=info
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true
minfds=1024
minprocs=200
directory=/gp_flask/

[supervisorctl]

#[program:sshd]
#command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
#command=ls # a dummy command convenient for disabling nginx

[program:gunicorn]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn  -b 127.0.0.1:8001  "dear_flask.app:create_app()"
directory=/gp_flask/
```

Comment: Are you able to verify the same image is running that you just built? Would you list the steps you take to build, tag, push, and run the image remotely, plus the commands you run to see that the folder is empty when it's running? And with compose, would you show the contents of that yml, perhaps a volume is mounted at /gp_flask.

Comment: When I do <eval "$(docker-machine env gpflask)"> and then simply do
 <docker build -t gp_flask .> and then in another terminal repeat the eval and then start a shell on the container <docker exec -it mad_fermat /bin/bashls> the COPY has clearly worked. So the Dockerfile is good, even on the remote EC2 instance. I will add the .yml to the question, but docker-compose works every time when I run it locally on my linux machine. I only ran into this problem when docker-machine become involved.

Comment: As to how I see that /gp_flask is empty when doing docker-compose, I simply docker-compose exec website /bin/bash

Comment: if you run docker build through docker-machine the file you COPY should be in ec2 host, not your machine

Comment: you can use local contents to aws with docker-machine scp -r local/path/to/file $DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME:/same/path

Comment: but proper way to do this is using private registry and tag and push to that and pull from aws

Comment: Oh. thanks. I had no idea about COPY from my machine not "just working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your compose file, you replace the contents of /gp_flash with a host volume (bind mound):

```
  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      /usr/bin/supervisord
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/gp_flask'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '5000:5000'
      - '5001:5001'
```

This results in the /gp_flask folder in your container having whatever is in the `.` directory. Locally, this will work. But on a remote server, the docker compose command will likely reference an empty or non-existent folder as you're seeing in your AWS environment. If you remove the volume reference, you will see the contents of your image as expected. And if you need a volume for persistent storage, consider using a named volume which will initialize to the contents of your image the first time you use it. E.g.:

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.5'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass devpassword
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      /usr/bin/supervisord
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - 'gp_flask:/gp_flask'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '5000:5000'
      - '5001:5001'

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery worker -l debug -A dear_flask.dear.tasks
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    depends_on: 
      - website
    volumes:
      - 'gp_flask:/gp_flask'

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
  gp_flask:
```

You should ensure that the image that contains this folder populated with files is the first to start, or that no other containers write to the folder before the source container starts. To do that, use a depends_on similar to how I've shown celery depends on website.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense and it works too :) The docs say that volumes are inititialised when the container is created. In this case the directory contains code that will change. What should the workflow be?

Comment: Docker doesn't initialize host volumes (bind mounts), only named volumes. So if you mount a directory from the host, it only contains the files that currently exist on the docker host (which, if there's a VM, may not be the same as the location where you are running docker commands). If you want to update a named volume, I've been known to run some kind of sync routine (rsync, scp, git pull, and most often a `tar -xf -` command with input piped from stdin into the docker run command). The sync routine can be a completely different image/container with the same volume mounted.

Comment: thanks. I have learnt a lot from your answer. will use git I think. Then the workflow looks like this:http://blog.ionic.io/docker-hot-code-deploys/